# Removing a DNS network configuration is impossible because the minus button is grayed out

Tags: dns, system-settings, profile-manager

I remember adding a DNS service (NextDNS) via a profile some time ago. Unfortunately I cannot remove it from the Network list in System Preferences because the minus button is grayed out.

Surprisingly the profile has disappeared, and there is no Profile icon in System Preferences. This is weird since another profile is installed and works well (a Wifi profile) but is not accessible anymore.

I tried several solutions listed in other StackExchange questions such as:

```sh
$ networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Which returns:

```
Wi-Fi
Bluetooth PAN
Thunderbolt Bridge
```

So the DNS service is not listed.

I then try to edit `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` but the DNS service is not listed here neither, there is only the 3 services mentioned above.

I also tried to list the profiles manually using `profile list` but it says there are no installed profiles.

I wonder if I'm even editing the right `preferences.plist` file. I did a search for a file with the same name system wide but did not find useful results.

Comment: Are you able to add a config profile to place the network in the desired state? Also  - what is the network setting for your preferred interface? DHCP or manual or DHCP with manual address? If you can describe your desired outcome we might be able to help script enforcing the setup you want

Comment: Yes I can add and disable services and the changes are reflected (the DNS is effectively disabled). I'm using Wifi with DHCP. Globally I'm using default settings with 2 other configurations (a DNS and Avast Security stuff).

Comment: Network configuration is fine, I just do not like the fact that I cannot remove a network service of manage installed profiles.

Comment: If you have a single greyed-out DNS showing in that list, it's because it has been picked up from DHCP usually. Add a new custom DNS & the DHCP should be replaced. Remove it & it will go back to DHCP, grey. Check what your Router shows as, in TCP/IP panel & maybe try renewing your lease. 'Stock' defaults are usually the same for router & DNS.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not talking about the DNS menu of the Wifi service (in the advanced pane) but a DNS service in the list at the left of the Network pane.

Comment: hmm… OK. Never seen one of those. Sorry, I can't help.